# When to create a Panel for CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jpanel, cardlayout

I use CardLayout with MVC and try to understand, when i should create the Panels used by the CardLayout.

For Example:

A DetailPanel to view and edit the Details of a DataItem is shown, when i select the DataItem on a ListPanel.
Should i create and show DetailPanel when i select the DataItem, or should i create the DetailPanel at the start of my Application and just call a load method, when i select the DataItem, and then show the DetailPanel?

Currently i'm using CardLayout like a Stack. I add a Panel when i need it and remove it when i'm done editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid *replacing* view components. Initially, create as much of a `DetailPanel` as possible and *update* the component [models](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html#separable) in your `ListSelectionListener`. Use `CardLayout` for the variable portion of each `DetailPanel`. It's unlikely that creating the view will have a perceptible performance impact; [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to see. If you find that constructing the model introduces significant latency, consider `SwingWorker`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692).